# JavaScript Converting \n to \r\n

Tags: javascript, regex, line-breaks

I am having some trouble converting simple \n to \r\n in JavaScript

```
var text = "Test1\nTest2\nTest3";

 var converted = text.replace("/\\n/g", "\r\n");
```

Does anyone see what's wrong with the above JS? I am trying to do a global replace of \n with \r\n.

The above code does not do the conversion and leaves the \n-s

Comment: How did you know it did not work ? try the below 
`text.replace("/\\n/g", "\\r\\n")`

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly Your example won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regExp:

```
var converted = text.replace(/(\r)?\n/g, "\r\n");
```

Comment: No need in parentheses: `/\r?\n/g`.